# Want to be able to redirect readers to another wordpress site but still be able to access the back end of current site

Tags: redirect, admin

I had done this once before but cannot find my notes for it. I want to be able to redirect readers to another WordPress site, but still be able to access the back end of the current site. Basically it's hiding a site from the public sending them to another site but keeping it up for the admin to access content, yet. I have notes about how to allow admin-only access by way of .htaccess rules using IP addresses, but that would not redirect. I want to be able to redirect everyone but the admin away from the site.

How would that be done?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with the "template_redirect" hook. For multisite or simple WordPress. e.g:

```
add_action('template_redirect', function(){

    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    $userRoles = $user->roles;

    $url = site_url();

    if(!in_array('administrator', $userRoles) && !is_front_page()){
        wp_redirect($url);
        exit;
    }

});
```

**EDIT**
is_front_page() will work only if "Front page displays" is set. Use is_home() if not.

**EDIT #2**
Accordind with our discuss below, an example for when you play with multisite and you want redirect according to the current site:

```
add_action('template_redirect', function(){

    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    $userRoles = $user->roles;

    $url = get_home_url(3);

    if(!in_array('administrator', $userRoles) && get_current_blog_id() != 3){
        wp_redirect($url);
        exit;
    }

});
```

Comment: Thanks, Sam for the answer. It looks like the if statement is saying "if in the array the user role is 'administrator', and trying to use the front page [or home page], redirect to this other url, otherwise go off the site.' I want all regular readers to be redirected to another of the owner's sites. It looks like you're saying that the admin would get redirected to another site.

Comment: @DavidBorrink You are making a small error of understanding : my code is saying "if you are not the admin and you are not on the front page, redirect to the front page. Just, i'm not sure when you talking if you have a multisite or regular site wordpress, but the principle remains the same: check current blog id, redirecto to a specific blog id. I'll adjust my answer for add an example.

Comment: Thanks for sharing more, Sam. I see. I overlooked the "!" which meant "not" . Are you saying this will allow the log-in page to exist as usable? This is only for one site to go to another, and is not a multi-site situation.

Comment: I believe the /wp-login.php page will not be affected. Right now, I can't test it and I don't remember it. If the Login Admin Page is affected, you can play with the is_admin() boolean in your condition. (or the boolean is_page() if your connection is on a custom page .... But in fact, I don't even believe that is_admin() affects the Login page. I think you will be ok.)

Comment: But in fact, I don't even believe that is_admin() affects the Login Admin Page. I think you will be ok if you don't have a custom page for your login.

Comment: I gave it a try. I put it in the functions.php file, and added the site I wanted to redirect to. Format used:  $url = site_url('FULL URL OF SITE HERE');  

I then went to the site to see if the login page was available, and it was, I then was able to go to the front page. When I went to an inside blog post page, I got "a critical error has happened to this site" message. I wasn't logged in, FYI. I did the edits from the server files.

Comment: site_url() will return your wordpress URL website. Replace site_url() by your url instead of place your url inner the function. Put a look here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/site_url/

Comment: If you have again your error, show me your codes in your functions.php with pastebin or codepen

Comment: btw, for get more informations about your error, add this in your wp-config.php: https://pastebin.com/zkUqw7cp ... Just, remember turn it to false on production server for more security. In the same time, if you can show me the error with your pastebin/codepen codes, it'll be the best!

Comment: The @Nadal method is good too, but wp_redirect() manage HTTP status for indicate to your bots, what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The ideal method to avoid upsetting search bots that view redirection to other site as deceptive and likely will blacklist, is to set a new home page with the statement that the site has moved and provide a link for user and bots to follow.

That said, if the preference is to automate the action, you'll be better off setting an array of IP addresses that will not be redirected.

**functions.php**

```php
$allowed_ip = ['12.34.56.7','12.34.56.8'];
function vip() 
{
    if( isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']) ) {
        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    }elseif( isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']) ) {
        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    }else{
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
    
    return $ip;
}

if( !in_array(vip(), $allowed_ip) ) {
  wp_redirect('https://example.com');
  exit;
}
```